# Prepare mysql row for use in IN() clause

Tags: mysql, search

I need to find rows that contain a specific number in a set of numeric values that are stored in a table. I'm using the `WHERE IN()` function of mysql, but I'm having problems with the proper format.

Basically I have the following query:

```
SELECT id,category, text
FROM ws_cat
WHERE '11' IN (category)
```

The category field is a `VARCHAR` and looks like the following:

```
id    category
1     11
2     12,11
3     1,13,9
```

So I need to find the rows with id 1 and 2 in this case. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I'm guessing it's because of the missing quotes, but all the ideas of reformating with `QUOTES()` or just changing the format of `category` to something like `'12','11'` wouldn't work either. Both would be possible for me as long as it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT id, category, text
    FROM ws_cat
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('11', category) <> 0;
```